# Кастомные поля для Paypal

Tags: php, paypal

Можно ли задавать кастомные поля и получать их в ответе от IPN?

```
private function prepare_payment($params){
        $requestParams = array(
            'RETURNURL'                   => base_url().'/account/proadvertisers/payment_response',
            'CANCELURL'                   => base_url().'/account/proadvertisers',
            'BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION' => $params['type'].' Membership',
            'BILLINGTYPE'                 => 'RecurringPayments',
        );

        $orderParams = array(
            'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT'           => calcPrice($params['price']),
            'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT'   => '0',
            'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE'  => 'USD',
            'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT'       => calcPrice($params['price']),
            'BRANDNAME'                      => 'GuestCrew',
            'NOSHIPPING'                     => '1',
            'LOGOIMG'                        => base_url()."assets/frontend/images/logo_guest_crew_black-150.jpg",
            'ALLOWNOTE'                      => '0',
            'GIFTRECEIPTENABLE'              => '0',
            'GIFTMESSAGEENABLE'              => '0',
            'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CUSTOM'        => 'Custom Item'
        );

        $item = array(
            'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0' => $params['type'],
            'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0'  => calcPrice($params['price']),
            'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0'  => '1'
        );

        $response = $this->paypal->SetExpressCheckout($requestParams + $orderParams + $item);
        if(is_array($response) && $response['ACK'] == 'Success'){
            $token = $response['TOKEN'];
            header('Location: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token='.urlencode($token));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Попробуйте использовать поле custom в объекте transaction запроса к PayPal.

Comment: Пишут что поле кастом игноритуется при создании платежей с абонентской платой!

Comment: Вы бы тогда уточнили, какой запрос вы делаете, на какой метод API

Comment: на SetExpressCheckout